# CodeIgniter - Select controller based on database

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm building a simple CMS using Code Igniter version 3.0.0

The site's URLs are all customizable by the user and so do not follow the standard MVC structure of /controller/method/parameter-1/parameter-2/. Instead, all frontend traffic gets directed to PublicController's index method.  This method searches the database for the current URL to return the correct page, and also the page type.  Each page type corresponds to a controller.

How do I call that controller from the PublicController without doing a redirect?

I can't use the `redirect()` method because that would change the URL in the browser window and cause an un-need additional page request.

Comment: Your question is very broad and very unclear.  Please narrow it down to something specific.   The exact Controller is determined by the very first URL segment... this can be tweaked further by using custom Routes (in config).  Otherwise, [the docs very clearly explain the MVC concept](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/index.html)... read it and follow [the tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html).   Also FYI, 3.0 has been released, so there's no need to use the development version.

Comment: Okay I will rewrite it as it seems like all the answers have misunderstood.  The latest version is 3.0.1-dev - I which I will update to

Comment: The `dev` version is a "not yet officially released developer version".  The latest official version from codeigniter.com is simply `3.0.0`.

Comment: The question is rewriten. Hopefully it makes more sense.  Additionally I've updated to version 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the url /about/who-we-are/ 
about is the controller and who-we-are is a function in the controller that loads one or more views.

The same for /locations/stores/
the functions stores in the controller locations.

read the documentation and it will be easy to understand.
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however In the example, 'about' isn't a controller, it's a page URL set by the user. The Controller the URL is mapped to is specified with in the database

Comment: @anotheruser1488182, then you need to write a Controller that can retrieve and redirect to this URL.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that configuring a route is your answer:

```
// routes.php
$route['(:any)'] = "PublicController/index/$1";

// PublicController.php
public function index()
{
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}
```